# Whenever I run npm start the same "error" message appears "No production canister_ids.json found. Continuing production

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-start, motoko, dfinity

After having done the `dfx deploy --network ic`
I got this error. Whenever I run npm start the same "error" message appears `No production canister_ids.json found. Continuing production`
`[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/alexasfils/ic-projects/dbank/webpack.config.js' config [webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

I tried: these commands:
`npm install --save-dev webpack-cli , npm upgrade --save-dev webpack-cli, npm install webpack-cli@4.10.0 --save-dev but it didn't help me`